# Can't add action on UIButton storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, storyboard

Sorry for my stupid question. I use storyboard and have got some screens. With first screen all was ok, but the next make me this question. I can't drag and drop UIButton to code to make a property... So, this situation you can see on the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8pSu.jpg

Help, please. Thank you.

Comment: did u give the custom class for that screen?

Comment: Yes, I've got. But I also can't drag button on it

Comment: Changing the name to Custom Class name would be enough. If you still can't drag and drop, just quit your xcode and try the same process again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vica,

In the storyboard, make sure you select the view controller for the Nanny scene.
From the Identity Inspector on the right side make sure you change the class from UIViewController to ViewController.

I hope it would help you :)

Comment: I see you have selected a label on the view of the scene, but I told you to select the View Controller (Yellow color in the Document Outline). See here an example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5wl0tyolwlwit1/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-28%20at%202.07.49%20AM.png

Comment: But why I can't add action the same way?

Comment: Please let me see a screenshot for which element and where you do want to add actions.

Comment: That is a UILabel I believe. It is not possible to add IBAction to it. Only for controls like buttons, slider, segmented controls etc. If you want to make a label editable, use UITextField instead, and set it's border to none, and play with its properties to make it look like a label.

Comment: What kind of action were you trying to add to that label?

Comment: Sorry, but if I need to change UILabel after taping one button what is the most nice way to do it?

Comment: just add an IBOutlet to the label, and an action to the button you want to tap, and inside that method type: self.myLabel.text = @"nutella";

Comment: Is here all correct?- (IBAction)addingHasTaped:(id)sender {
    NetworkConnection *request = [[NetworkConnection alloc]init];
 
   [request getDataFromServer];
    
    self.personalIDLabel.text = @"one two";

     NSLog(@"serviceId = %@", request.getServiceID);
}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the class which your are trying to add an Action to is assigned to your ViewController through Storyboards, Check in your Identity Inspector if the ViewControlller is assigned to the same class you are adding the code to

Answer (score 0):

Make IBActions/IBOutlets manually in your class and connect from "code" to button in storyboard (by dragging from circles left to declarations). E.g.

[image]